# Frequency in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to add frequency capping to all daily emails so customer does not receive more than 3 emails per day? And we do alot of resends so if they received AM email and did not click then do not move them to next email

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any standard way of achieving this in SFMC. I can think of three ways to do this:

- Develop the solution yourself
- Use an app that already does this
- Use Einstein Engagement Frequency (in a custom way)

Designing and developing a solution to this problem can come with some challenges depending on what's in your account and how you run your sends. Suppose you are using only Journey Builder for sends. In that case, you can leverage Sent data view or the SendLog, and decision splits/exit criteria/goal to eject the contact from the journey or send him on a different path.

Or, you can use an app like [DESelect Engage](https://support.deselect.com/hc/en-us/categories/13496825532817-DESelect-Engage). I have seen a demo of this app, and it seems interesting. The hick? it comes with a cost ;)

The third option is [EEF](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_anb_eef.htm&type=5), but in a custom way like I said. Create a journey and an automation to inject all your contact into it daily. Inside the journey, add and configure the EEF activity, and create paths with the different statuses available with this module (Saturated, undersaturated,...). In each path, add an update activity with the corresponding status. This way, you'll let EEF do all the work and have a status for each of your contact. You can then use this field inside your journeys to exclude/eject contacts depending on their statuses. The hicks? You are letting Einstein do all the job (black-box), and I personally have experienced some random and illogical results using it.

I'll be interested to see how others are approaching this problem...

Answer (score 1):

For the "develop the solution yourself" option, you can use auto-suppression lists (data extensions).  I've got an example here:

https://github.com/wvpv/sfmc-frequency-suppression

The 3 emails/day restriction could be problematic with this solution, since you have to keep track of sends multiple times per day.  That's a lot of data to churn through depending on your send volume.

Whenever I hear of frequency suppression, I always question *why* its even necessary from a strategy perspective.  If your recipients are wanting fewer emails, why not just send fewer instead of trying to suppress by volume?